# QCustomPlot несколько графиков

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

Не могу понять, почему не рисуются графики с индексами `i + 1`, хотя в официальном туториале просто задается номер графика и ему задается цвет?

У меня рисуется только ui->widget->graph(0), почему такое может быть?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QVector>
#include <fstream>
#include <QMap>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFile aFile("C:/Users/SanyaBooster/Documents/Lab2/qq.txt");
    QTextStream qwqe(&aFile);
    aFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    verticalLine = new QCPCurve(ui->widget->xAxis, ui->widget->yAxis);
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; ++i){
        double q, w;
        qwqe >> q >> w;
        qDebug() << q << " " << (1 - w) << endl;
        x.push_back(q);
        y.push_back(w);
    }
    ui->widget->addGraph();
    ui->widget->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(QColor("red")));
    ui->widget->graph(0)->addData(x, y);
    ui->widget->rescaleAxes();
    ui->widget->replot();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QVector<double> _y0, _x0;
    double p = ui->lineEdit->text().toDouble();

    if(p > 1){
        QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
        reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Warning", "0 <= p <= 1", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
        if(reply == QMessageBox::Yes || reply == QMessageBox::No){
            QApplication::quit();
        }
    } else {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        double lyambda = 0;
        QVector<double> mu;

        for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; ++i) {
            mu.push_back((double)(1.0 / i));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            std::normal_distribution<double> d(p, mu[i]);
            double tmp = d(gen);
            if (tmp >= lyambda) {
                lyambda += mu[i] * (1 - p);
            } else {
                lyambda += mu[i] * (-p);
            }
            qDebug() << lyambda << endl;
            ui->widget->addGraph();
            ui->widget->graph(i+1)->setPen(QPen(QColor("green")));
            ui->widget->graph(i+1)->addData(lyambda, 0);
            ui->widget->rescaleAxes();
            ui->widget->replot();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ужос ) Короче, у вас каждый график, кроме первого это точка `ui->widget->graph(i+1)->addData(lyambda, 0);` https://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPGraph.html#a0bf98b1972286cfb7b1c4b7dd6ae2012 Миллион графиков-точек. Сильно

Comment: @AlexanderChernin точно)))))